# Microcontroller logic level characteristics

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic

I would like to know what are the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM of the low level input voltage and the MINIMUM and MAXIMUM of the high level input voltage.

(I am looking for the voltage levels required to recognize a high or low state)

Here is what I find into the following datasheet : https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32f072rb.pdf

[image]

Nevertheless there is no information about minimum when talking about low level input voltage and there is no information about maximum when talking about high level input voltage.

[image]

Thank you very much and have a nice day !

Comment: GND and VCCIO of course.

Comment: To answer your additional question, the range between between Vih and Vil is undefined. Any given voltage may be recognized as high or low or, depending on the logic family, might cause excessive current flow through the IC and damage it. Also, the result of a given voltage might change from unit to unit or based on temperature or age of the parts. If you want a reliable circuit, you should not use a voltage between Vih and Vil except, of course, briefly during a transition.

Comment: Ok really nice answer ! Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That table is only showing you the voltage levels required to recognize a high or low state.

To see the operating minimums and maximums, you need to look instead at the General Operating Conditions table:
[image]
Here, under Vin, you’ll see the normal operating minimum and maximum voltages.

Edit: the OP has clarified that he is looking for the full range of valid voltages for an input low or high. Since the I/O Static Characteristics does not specify a minimum VinL or maximum VinH, this means that the range goes all the way to the minimum or maximum allowed voltage, as read from the a General Operating Conditions Vin.

For example, for TC I/O, Vin low ranges from -0.3 volts to 0.445 * Vddiox + 0.398 volts.

Comment: I am not looking for the operating voltages. My question was not clear, i am looking for as you said the voltage levels required to recognize a high or low state.

Comment: @Jess But if the first table says that the maximum Vin for low is X and not specify a minimum, this implies that any valid lower voltage is fine. Thus, you need to then look at the minimum valid operating voltage to find that low end.

Comment: I do not understand the table like this ... It should be written the MAXIMUM for the high level input voltage. What tell me that my microcontroller has the minimum and not the maximum level for recognizing a high level voltage ? If it was the MAXIMUM which would be written, I would be sure that if my voltage if higher than the maximum voltage it would be interpreted as a high level voltage. Doesn't it ?

Comment: @Jess You are certainly free to continue increasing the the Vin and the chip will continue to see it as a high input, all the way until you cause the chip to malfunction or blow due to excessive voltage. There is no maximum Vin high because any voltage above minimum Vin high is a high. There just is a limit to how high a voltage you can safely give the chip! 25 volts in is a high but will destroy the chip.

Comment: See my edit. What do you think ?

Answer (score 2):

Anything over \$V_{DD}\$ is liable to damage the microcontroller.

Anything over \$V_{IH}\$ is a high input

Anything below \$V_{IL}\$ is a low input.

Anything below \$V_{SS}\$ is liable to damage the microcontroller.

Anything between  \$V_{IL}\$ abd \$V_{IH}\$ is an undeterminend logic level.

so anythig between \$V_{IH}\$ and \$V_{DD}\$ is a good logic high input signal.

and anything between \$V_{IL}\$  and \$V_{SS}\$ is a good logic low input signal.

Actually it's often \$V_{DD} + 0.3V\$ and  \$V_{SS} - 0.3V\$ but I left that out above to simplify it.

Comment: I agree with you but VIH is given into the datasheet as its minimum and not as its maximum ... So if on a certain microcontroleur VIH is higher than its minimum, if i have a voltage slightly higher than the minimum VIH given into the datasheet and lower than the maximum VIH (which is not given into the datasheet), so I would be in the region where the logic level is undertermined ... @Jasen

Comment: actual VIH will be almost exactly the same as actual VIL but the values of this theshold is not given in the datasheet and may not be constant

Comment: @Jasen Please note that the MCU has 5V tolerant pins that can handle more than VDD without damage which the simplification also does not take into account.

Answer (score 0):

Vss-0.3V and 4.0V as per *6.2 Absolute maximum ratings*

Comment: While you are indeed pointing out the **absolute** minimums and maximums, he’s probably more interested in the normal operating minimums and maximums.

Comment: @DoxyLover Those would be Vss and Vdd, very irrelevant.

Comment: My take is that the OP wants the threshold voltages for where something is treated as 1 or 0.